# Is there any way of shortening a class property string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a discord bot with the discord.py lib and I'm frequently using long segments of text like `ctx.message.author.id`.
   Is there any way of aliasing it to something like "author_id", so instead of typing `ctx.message.author.id` I can just write `author_id`?

Comment: If used 'more than once' within a scope, perhaps just a local variable: `author_id = ctx.message.author.id; print(author_id); print(author_id);` (it's not "alias" of the original expression; rather a different name for the original value it evaluated as)

Comment: `author_id = ctx.message.author.id` ?

Comment: "ctx" is not the same everytime.

Comment: The `1.0` release [added some shortcuts to `Context` objects](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#context-changes), so you can use `ctx.author.id` instead

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Thank you very much, I didn't know that.